# Vertical align text on div not works when I have multiple paragraphs

Tags: html, css

I using the following extra-simple HTML code:

```
<div class="test">
    <p>test 1234</p>
    <!--<p>test 5678</p>-->
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.test {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 120px;
}

.test p {
    line-height: 120px;
}
```

Jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/wP9K3/

It works fine

But if I un-comment the second paragraph from above HTML code then the display is not good. (remove from jsfiddle the comments and run it).

How to make in CSS that the `n` paragraphs to be aligned one under other without space ?

In first case, the display is (is good):

[image]

Second case, not good:

[image]

My expectation:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wP9K3/5/

Comment: Great solution! Just in case the link breaks, how about adding the `html` and `css` in the answer as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
​.test {
    background-color : #ccc;
    height : 120px;
    display : table-cell;
    vertical-align : middle;    
}​
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/st3aB/

Answer (score 0):

**Code structure is**

```
<style>
.test {
    background: #ccc;
    height: auto;
    width:100px;
}

.test p {
    line-height: 50px;
}
​</style>

<div class="test">
    <p>test 1234</p>
    <p>test 5678</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wP9K3/16/